# constraints not being fully incorporated Play 2.1

Tags: java, html, playframework, formhelper

Was wondering why the constraints created for a form are not included in the input tag directly when created through the form helper?

Explanation (using Play 2.1):

Model:

```
public class Account {
    @MaxLength(5)
    private String id = "";
```

...
...

view:
    @form(action = routes.Application.addAccount()) {
      @inputText(accountForm("id"), '_label -> "Enter your id:")
      
    }

renders automatically in html as:

Enter your id:

Maximum length: 5

Should it not render like this (actually constraining the form text field):

Enter your id:

Maximum length: 5

How can I get code that will automatically include constraints such as these in the form?  It's just that I do not really think it is a good idea to have a maxlength defined in the form model and a separate one defined in the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, it sounds like you're looking to implement one of these features:

- Highlight an input text field that is overlength before form submission
- Clipping text in an input field so that it does not go overlength

Play's HTML templating engine doesn't natively provide this kind of client-side instant form validation. This functionality needs to be implemented via JavaScript, and JavaScript generation is not really a concern for Play.

If you want to progressively enhance your form and provide client-side validation, you'll have to write the JavaScript yourself. Of course there are libraries that you can use to help you with this task. For example, if you are already using jQuery you can use its [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

As you've mentioned in your question, it would be better to have a maximum length limit declared in one place only, rather than duplicated in your client-side JavaScript code and your server-side Java code. As a suggestion, you could keep the limit declared in Java code, but introduce a new action in your controller tier that returns a JSON response containing this limit. This action could then be called via AJAX when loading your form page.

---

#### EDIT

Didn't know about the `maxlength` attribute, thanks [Saad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813499/constraints-not-being-fully-incorporated-play-2-1#comment31212543_20815181). If you feed in your maximum length limit as an input parameter to your template, you can populate an `input` element's `maxlength` attribute as follows:

```
@(accountForm: Form[Account], maxLength: Int)

...
  @form(action = routes.Application.addAccount()) { 
    ...
    @inputText(
      field = accountForm("id"), 
      args = '_label -> "Enter your id:", 'maxlength -> maxLength
    )
    ...
  }
...
```

There may be a more elegant way to pass `maxLength` into your HTML template (e.g use the HTTP context map, or have it as a public field on your `Account` form object). The above code snippet just demonstrates how to correctly generate the input text field once you can access it in the template.

Comment: Thanks - really informative.  Just to clarify though, if you provide the maxlength parameter to the input field - several browsers appear to automatically limit the input to three characters.  you are saying there is no way for the field constructor to automatically gather this info rather than including it manually?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the `maxlength` attribute that can be specified on an input element. Thanks Saad. I've updated my answer in light of your comment.

Comment: that way appears to be the best for the me moment so I guess I'll go ahead with that.  But I was thinking, you don't think there would be a way to override/edit the method that creates the html so that it automatically gathers constraints?  I mean it definitely already takes account of constraints by including the text maximum length 5.  It just does not also include it in the input parameter as we've said.